# Macro to manage sport ranking and calendar?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, calendar, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I need to write a macro (or a different easy way) to manage ranking and calendar for a curling tournament.

The event will follow the Shenkel system:

1. first match determined by general draw
2. after that every team has played one match is possible to determine the first ranking
3. second match determined by the rule: 1st vs. 2nd - 3rd vs. 4th - 5th vs. 6th and so on
4. after that every team has played two matches is possible to determine the second ranking

and so on until the end (3 to 5 matches, normally).

Another rule is that the second match should not repeat a game pairing (e.g., *X* vs. *Y*) that occurred in the previous match.

I was thinking to use Microsoft Excel, but also Calc (both LibreOffice/OpenOffice) should be fine.

I am able to determine point 1. (but it is not necessarily a macro for it).

I am also able to determine the ranking after the first match (point 2.)

I am able to generate the calendar 1st vs. 2nd - 3rd vs. 4th... but I am not able to check if a team has just played before with the same team.

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I have edited the post with your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your need correctly you need something like this :

[image]

That, at white cells you can find all games like (Team3 vs. Team6) in `D7`, and if that team in column `A` (Team6) is winner scored by 1 and if is looser scored by 0;  and automatically the light gray cell `G4` Scored.

Then you have a rank of sum of wins.

The light gray cells formula is:

```
=IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN();ROW()))= ""; 0; 1 - INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN();ROW())))
```

And Gray cells are : `= 0` and Rank Column formula is a simple SUM

Comment: This case is when every team plays with all other team, while in my case every team plays less match than the number of opposition team. In the example every team will play probably 3 or 4 match so not all the cells will be populated

Comment: @Ale I delete that Excel file but If you don't enter a value to with cells the related gray cell will be also `0`, If that's your need I can handle it again ;).

Comment: Ok, this solve the case of do not re-match a game with the same team. Now I should find a way to do all the passages in a easy and automatic way :)

Comment: @Ale I add the formula for that light gray Cells.